# flex and flex-flow not validating

Tags: css, validation, flexbox

For my school project, we're required to validate the CSS but for some reason, it refuses to accept flex as a display property and and display-direction as an attribute. I'm not sure if I made a mistake or if this is indeed correct.

I even set the validator is validate CSS3.

http://www.css-validator.org/validator

http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_flex-flow.asp

```
.summary, .bio, .http, .terms, .citation {
width:75%; 
min-width: 812px; 
margin:auto; 
margin-top: 1em; 
margin-bottom: 3em;
display: flex;
color: #585858;}

.summary {
flex-direction: row;}

.bio, .terms, .citation {
flex-direction: column;}

figure{
display: flex;}
```

Answer (score 0):

The validator at http://www.css-validator.org/validator seems to be a clone of https://jigsaw.w3.org/css-validator/validator.

When you run the latter with level set to CSS level 3 it tells you that it has not found any errors. So I guess the first validator seems to somehow drop the CSS level param or is based on old validation code. Anyway your code is fine.